# What components will I need to create a PA system?

Tags: purchase-advice

I am wanting to create a rack mounted PA system for use at a camp. I am wanting to build it to support 3-5 speakers, 4 wireless mics, and 2+ corded mics as well as having a aux port to play from a phone or computer.

What components would I need to get to build this and what product recommendations do you have? I currently have no equipment and need help to build this system. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with sound design.

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic. consumer product recommendations are not allowed here. See the [help] page for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider before deciding what equipment you need because there are so many options; Such as, budget and how large of an area you need to cover with the system. You can buy portable rack mount cases from a few websites. You will also need to buy a mixing console with a number of inputs that matches or exceeds your mics/computer devices. It is pretty difficult to set you up here on the forum. I would recommend contacting professional audio suppplier such as [Sweeetwater Sound](http://Sweetwater.com). They have sales engineers that will be able to fully assist you and provide the equipment you need and try to work with your budget.